# Multilevel aggregation with rollup combinations

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose that I have the following data

```
data <- 
structure(list(Age = c(">30", ">30", ">30", ">30", ">30", ">30", 
">30", ">30", "<=30", "<=30", "<=30", "<=30", "<=30", "<=30", 
"<=30", "<=30"), Experience = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", 
"No"), State = c("Lusiana", "Lusiana", "Lusiana", "Lusiana", 
"Lusiana", "Lusiana", "Lusiana", "Lusiana", "Lusiana", "Lusiana", 
"Lusiana", "Lusiana", "Lusiana", "Lusiana", "Lusiana", "Lusiana"
), City = c("Houma", "Houma", "Ruston", "Ruston", "Houma", "Houma", 
"Ruston", "Ruston", "Houma", "Houma", "Ruston", "Ruston", "Houma", 
"Houma", "Ruston", "Ruston"), Salary = c(1200, 1100, 1400, 1500, 
1000, 1300, 2000, 1500, 1200, 1100, 1400, 1500, 1000, 1300, 2000, 
1500)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

top of the data

```
  Age   Experience State   City   Salary
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>   <chr>   <dbl>
1 >30   Yes        Lusiana Houma    1200
2 >30   Yes        Lusiana Houma    1100
3 >30   Yes        Lusiana Ruston   1400
4 >30   Yes        Lusiana Ruston   1500
5 >30   No         Lusiana Houma    1000
6 >30   No         Lusiana Houma    1300
```

In this case I want to calculate the max salary by city and the sum of these values for the state and I want to do it for each combination of Age and Experience.

Expected Output is

[image]

Another doubt that I have

[image]

is there a way in rollup to force the same level as different combination in rollup? I mean treat A + B and B + A as different combination?

Comment: Can you please include expected outcome for these 6 rows

Comment: @AnilGoyal I edited the question and put another example with expected output

Comment: But it is still not clear which is apparent from someone's downvote.  Please include desired outcome after manually calculating it for the sample given!

Comment: @AnilGoyal edited again with complete expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the `max` salary in each `City` and `sum` them for each `State`.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(Age, Experience, State, City) %>%
  summarise(Salary = max(Salary)) %>%
  summarise(Salary = sum(Salary), .groups = 'drop')

#  Age   Experience State   Salary
#  <chr> <chr>      <chr>    <dbl>
#1 <=30  No         Lusiana   3300
#2 <=30  Yes        Lusiana   2700
#3 >30   No         Lusiana   3300
#4 >30   Yes        Lusiana   2700
```

If you want to do this in `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, .(Salary = max(Salary)), .(Age, Experience, State, City)][, 
              .(Salary = sum(Salary)), .(Age, Experience, State)]
```